Simplifying the conversion of a rational exponent to radical form
I've learned that $x^ \frac nm$ should be turned into radical form like $\sqrt[m]{x^n}$.
Therefore $10^ \frac32$ should be turned into radical form like $ \sqrt {10^3} $.
What I don't understand is how this is then further simplified to $10\sqrt10$.
Could anyone please explain the steps?

$\sqrt{10^3} = \sqrt{10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10} = \sqrt{10 \cdot 10^2} = 10 \sqrt{10}$

If $\sqrt{a}$ can be represented as $\sqrt{bc^2}$, then we can rewrite $\sqrt{a}$ as $c \sqrt{b}$.

$$\sqrt{10^3}=\sqrt{10^2\cdot10}=\sqrt{10^2}\cdot\sqrt{10}=10\sqrt{10}$$
Hope this helps. :)

It does! Thank you for the explanation!

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

@CrSb0001 can I ask how so?

@ultralegend5385 Sorry, should have included that in the comment. usually answers have to include more detail than this. If it's just this then it is better to just leave it as a comment.

@CrSb0001: They don't have to. Look at this meta post. Also, what I said is a complete answer, it surely should be posted as an answer, so it is marked accepted. Answers in comments are not good (see this).

@Mathseeker89: If it helped you, you should accept an answer (this or the other). To do so, click on the tick/check mark button on the top left of the answer. This makes sure your question is removed from the "unanswered" queue, so people don't spend time on this question anymore.

Recall from when you learned fractions that an improper or topheavy fraction may be turned into a mixed fraction, e.g.
\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{2}&=1\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{17}{5}&=3\frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}
Well, applying this to the exponent gives
$$10^{\frac{3}{2}}=10^{1\frac{1}{2}}=10^1\times 10^{\frac{1}{2}}=10\sqrt{10}$$
Likewise,
$$4^{\frac{17}{5}}=4^3\times 4^{\frac{2}{5}}=64\sqrt[5]{16}$$
